# Old Zener diode codes

Tags: power-supply, audio, preamp

I am trying to identify another Zener diode from a wem pa 100 pre amp, there is no spec on any of the various schematics I have seen, or to think of it there is never any on any WEM schematic for any product. It is bullet shaped silicon with 2 lots of numbers around it’s circumference, the first being, 1 ,followed by a diode symbol, R 70 44 then underneath those it has 1ZM 18 T5 or TS the 5/S is not very clear, any help would be most appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a photo of it?

Comment: There’s 36v from the power amp going through a560 ohm resistor and around 17v to the zener

Comment: Picture added but only shows part markings

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any picture added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [page](http://wem-owners.com/schematics/er40-er100-pa40-pa100/) with some schematics showing zeners in WEM amps. One is marked 4.7 so that one is pretty clear, another is being used as a shunt regulator where the regulated voltage is marked as 18 V, so that should be it’s zener voltage. I suspect yours may be 18 V as that number appears in the markings on it, but that’s not definite. You would need to either positively identify it in a schematic or come up with it’s voltage based on other voltages shown elsewhere in the schematic such as with the regulated 18 V in the one I linked.

Comment: @Paul In the link I provided look at the second row, first picture. It says 40/100W pre-amp at the bottom. There's a 560 ohm resistor at the top right, and a zener on the bottom right. Can you tell from the circuit if that's it? That's the one that should be 18V.

Comment: That’s the one , z 18v , the schematics I found just had z.d with Zener symbol from the 560 ohm resistor er100/15k er40., but yes that is the one

Comment: @Paul Okay great. Does this answer your question adequately then? I can make some changes if not.